# How can we make the summary field auto expand on load?

Tags: forms

We have an admin page with a summary and body. The summary is auto collapsed but we want it to be automatically expanded on the page load like below in the image.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  Please also try to provide more info on what you've tried yourself so far and where exactly you are stuck. Many thanks 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the [Summary Options](https://www.drupal.org/project/text_summary_options) module.

> This module provides site builders with additional options for the
> 'summary' field when using "Text Area with a Summary" widget.
>
> Often, a summary or teaser field is used when displaying content in
> views. Drupal already has built in support for a summary field,
> however there is not much control of whether or not it is display, or
> required.
>
> [image]